# Copying results of a function apply after groupby into a pandas column

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table, grouping

I am trying to do a `pandas` equivalent of the following `data.table` operations:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:10, x = rnorm(40))
dt <- dt[order(id)]
dt[, diff_x := c(0,diff(x)), by = id]

head(dt, 12)

# output:
    id           x      diff_x
 1:  1  0.01419519  0.00000000
 2:  1 -0.39539869 -0.40959388
 3:  1 -0.43918689 -0.04378821
 4:  1 -0.79905967 -0.35987278
 5:  2  0.59555572  0.00000000
 6:  2 -0.21933639 -0.81489211
 7:  2 -0.65462968 -0.43529329
 8:  2  0.99307684  1.64770652
 9:  3 -1.31185544  0.00000000
10:  3  1.23649358  2.54834902
11:  3  0.66359594 -0.57289764
12:  3  1.77078647  1.10719053
```

First of all, I am not sure how to do a `diff` in an easy way with padding that I did above, so I wrote my own function for that. But, more importantly, I am not sure how to copy the result of my `groupby` operation back into my `pandas` dataframe as a new column (the way I do easily above with `data.table`). Here is what I tried so far:

```
def diff_pad(vect):
    return(np.concatenate([[0], np.diff(vect)]))

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = list((range(1,11))) * 4
df.sort(['id'], inplace=True)
df['x'] = rand(40)

diffz = df.groupby('id')['x'].apply(diff_pad)

df['diffz'] = diffz
print(df.head(10))

#out:
    id         x                                              diffz
0    1  0.757153                                                NaN
30   1  0.869001                                                NaN
10   1  0.140684  [0.0, 0.362003972215, -0.742119725957, -0.0684...
20   1  0.791483                                                NaN
21   2  0.941333                                                NaN
1    2  0.504867  [0.0, 0.111848720078, -0.728317633944, 0.65079...
31   2  0.273321                                                NaN
11   2  0.118802                                                NaN
2    3  0.848048  [0.0, -0.436465430463, -0.231545666932, -0.154...
12   3  0.357192                                                NaN
```

**Edit:**

In R/data.table, I can apply an arbitrary function that takes any columns of the table grouped `by` another set of columns and assigns a result to a new column.

E.g.:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = 1:10, x = rnorm(40), y = rnorm(40))
dt <- dt[order(id)]

my_funct <- function(x, y) {
  return(sqrt(max(x)^2 + min(y)^2))
}

dt[, z := my_funct(x, y), by = id]

head(dt, 12)


# out:

    id           x          y         z
 1:  1  0.26012913  0.7612974 1.2433969
 2:  1  1.19113080  1.4228528 1.2433969
 3:  1 -0.07970657 -0.3567118 1.2433969
 4:  1 -0.33129374  0.7879845 1.2433969
 5:  2  0.60868698  0.9716669 0.8872687
 6:  2 -0.72751776  0.0392282 0.8872687
 7:  2 -0.17724141  0.2599093 0.8872687
 8:  2  0.13324134 -0.6455587 0.8872687
 9:  3 -1.91015664 -1.1340993 2.2408919
10:  3 -0.95696559 -0.2624625 2.2408919
11:  3  1.93272221  0.2788335 2.2408919
12:  3  0.46391776 -0.9080321 2.2408919
```

How would I do something like that in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st off, welcome to pandas!

Second, I'd start off defining `df` like this.  This is a style preference of mine and by no means canonical.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        id=np.repeat(np.arange(1, 11), 4),
        x=np.random.randn(40)
    ))
```

Lastly, if I understood you correctly:

```
df['x_diff'] = df.groupby('id').x.diff().fillna(0)
df
```

[image]

---

you could have used `apply` with your own function like this:

```
def my_diff(x):
    return x.diff().fillna(0)

df.groupby('id').apply(my_diff)
```

The reason yours didn't work was because you returned a numpy array with no index values to line up with the pandas series your function was being applied to.  You see in your results that the answer is there, but it's crammed into a single cell.

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick in this instance. But what if, instead of a diff, I had a need for some custom function which did some calculation with `x` (and maybe more columns). Is there a way to apply that function after `groupby` and then feed it back into a new column?

Comment: yes!  It's call `apply`.  Your issue was with how you defined your apply function.  I'll update my post.

Comment: In your edit, you’re still using a pandas function that you can apply to a series. What if I have to write my own function that does something customized and takes series (or a list) as an input? How do I apply it in such a way that I can assign the return to a new column (assuming that the number of elements returned = number of elements in each groupby)?

Comment: @Anarcho-Chossid your question is too vague.  There are so many ways to answer that.  I could take a guess as to what you need to see, but then you might just have another followup question.  What is it you need to calculate and let's go from there.  Or, what is a good proxy calculation that could help solidify your understanding.  Update your question.

Comment: I’ll update the question with an example, but my question is: why didn’t my Python example work?

Comment: Edited with an example of an R function.